# Alternative to Amazon S3 with GZIP compression

Tags: amazon-s3, static-site

I'm looking for an alternative to Amazon S3 for hosting static sites, but that allows GZIP compression depending on the Accept-Encoding header.

In other words, I'm looking for something that will return a different version of a file depending on the client's Accept-Encoding header. I don't mind uploading compressed and uncompressed files myself (it can be automated easily).

Besides that, the service needs to be capable of hosting websites (allows an index page and 404 page to be set). I don't need CNAME capabilities since I'll be using a CDN. I'd also like the capability to set caching headers (Expires, Last-Modified).

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace [Cloudfiles](https://www.rackspace.com/en-us/cloud/files) supports everything mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, my startup, [Site44](http://www.site44.com), does static hosting by syncing with Dropbox. We support all of this except the customized caching headers, but we'd be open to that feature request. (Today we set the Cache-Control header using a heuristic based on the last modified date, with a maximum value of 24 hours.)